# Fails to Generate Message

Tags: javascript, html, css

My message does not display after I run the code. Need some direction, I double checked my code. Might be a syntactical error somewhere

**HTML-**
<!doctype html>

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Message Generator</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <center><div class="wordart blues"><span class="text">Message Generator</span></div></center>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="quoteDisplay"><center>Your random message will be displayed here</center></div>
        <div id="quote">
            <!--Quote will display here-->
        </div>
        <center><button onclick="messageGenerator()">Click Here</button></center>
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Javascript-

```
const first = ["Mom", "Dad", "Uncle", "Dog", "Cat", "Brother", "Sister", "Aunt", "Random Stranger", "Respect", "Honor", "Dignity", "Brain", "Life"]
const second = ["Ocean", "Sea", "Volcano", "Tornado", "Ditch", "Cave", "Typhoon", "Asia", "India"]
const third=["Unknown","To explore","To prove a point","To live life with no constraints","Just cause"]

function randomGenerate(value) {
    var item = value[Math.floor(Math.random() * value.length)];
    return item;
}

const messageGenerator = () => {
    let person = randomGenerate(first);
    let place = randomGenerate(second);
    let reason = randomGenerate(third);
    let finalSentence = `Your ${person} jumped in the ${place}\nReason: ${reason}`;
```

document.getElementById("quoteDisplay").innerHTML=finalSentence;
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById("quoteDisplay")` looks for an element with ID of "quoteDisplay". In this case, your targeted element is a class.

```
document.querySelector('.quoteDisplay').innerHTML = finalSentence
```

Although, I think you are trying to target #quote, which in this case, `getElementById` is the right method but the wrong id

```
document.getElementById("quote").innerHTML = finalSentence;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your HTML

```
    <div class="quoteDisplay"><center>Your random message will be displayed here</center></div>
    <div id="quote">
```

Looking at your javascript
`document.getElementById("quoteDisplay").innerHTML=finalSentence;`

It should be `document.getElementById("quote").innerText = finalSentence;`